# Keyword errors in Abaqus

Tags: python, abaqus

I am currently trying to create two sets to assign two different material properties to my part in abaqus. I am using findAt to try and select cells to create a set from. On one of the cells (GEL_cell) will always be in a consistent point. However the other cell (PCL_cell) will not be so I run a line search and then filter all of the duplicate entries and GEL cell selections (see attached image). That method works to get me the two cells however when I actually try to create the set from those cells I get a keyword error. I have checked the data types on both GEL_cell and PCL_cell[0] and they are Cell types So I am truly not sure what is happening.

Here is the code block of issue:

```
    r = np.sqrt((centerx[i]*centerx[i])+(centery[i]*centery[i]))
    D = 0.2
    f_space = .6
    Model_str = 'Model-R' + str(int(r)) + ' FD' + str(int(D*1000)) + 'um FS' + str(int(f_space*1000)) +'um'    
    
    PCL_search = []
    PCL_linsearchx = np.linspace(-stampw/2,stampw/2,40)
    for k in range(0,int(len(PCL_linsearchx)-1)):
        PCL_search.append(mdb.models[Model_str].parts['Part-    4'].cells.findAt((PCL_linsearchx[k],stamph,1.5*b))) # PCL seach loops
        mdb.models[Model_str].rootAssembly.ReferencePoint(point=([PCL_linsearchx[k],stamph,3*b/2])) # reference points to see where my line search is

    GEL_cell = mdb.models[Model_str].parts['Part-4'].cells.findAt((0,0,0))
    

    PCL_fil = []
    [PCL_fil.append(x) for x in PCL_search if x not in PCL_fil] # removing duplicates and any of the cells that are the gel
    for k in range(0,int(len(PCL_fil)-1)):
        if PCL_fil[k] == GEL_cell:
            PCL_fil[k] = None
    
    PCL_fil = list(filter(lambda item: item is not None, PCL_fil)) # second filter of the line search
    PCL_cell = PCL_fil[0]

    print('PCL_cell: ', PCL_cell)
    print('GEL_cell: ', GEL_cell)
 
    
    print('gel type', type(GEL_cell))
    print('PCL type', type(PCL_fil[0]))
   
    
    GEL_set = mdb.models[Model_str].parts['Part-4'].Set(cells = GEL_cell, name= 'Gel-set') # point of error
    PCL_set = mdb.models[Model_str].parts['Part-4'].Set(cells= PCL_cell, name='PCL-set') #
```

[Sections and linesearch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxD5x.png)

I have output the PCL_cell and GEL_cell's themselves and they print out

mdb.models['Model-R36 FD200um FS600um'].parts['Part-4'].cells[0]
mdb.models['Model-R36 FD200um FS600um'].parts['Part-4'].cells[1]

Which makes sense given that these should be cell indexes and even when I print the type of the variables PCL_cell and GEL_cell I get Cell type, but they just cannot make a set from the cell type

Comment: What are the keyword errors?

Comment: I get a type error that says "keyword error on cells" on the line where I make my GEL_set

Comment: Can you copy and paste the exact and complete error message into your question?

Comment: The error is because `cells` or any other entity related option in `Set()` method accept value in a sequence. Can you try changing `cells = GEL_cell` to `cells = (GEL_cell, )`? Or to get cells in sequence, use `cells.findAt( ( (0,0,0) ,) )`.

Comment: Thanks Satish, changing the findAt line made GEL_cell type sequence and generated the Set. Now working on making PCL_cell the same thing